# Running two cURL scripts in same function seems to be blocking second action

Tags: php, function, curl

I have a script wherein I would like to send off two HTTPS calls to a master database via cURL with similar variables.  I have tested each script individually to be working fine, but when I combine the two the second one is blocked.  Here is what it looks like when they are combined:

```
$idno=’123’;


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mysite.com/integration.php?type=CANCEL&idnumber='.$idno.'');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$Response = curl_exec($curl);  
return $Response;
curl_close($curl);


$curl2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mysite.com/integration2.php?customer_id=CUSOTMER&idnumber='.$idno.’&type=CANCEL');
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$Response2 = curl_exec($curl2);  
return $Response2;
curl_close($curl2);
```

I have tried a handful of variations to open and close the cURL calls, but no luck.  Anything standing out here as off?

Comment: the syntax highlighting above points out a bug

Comment: I just sketched it out as a representation of the actual code.  Aside from the syntax highlighting is there any reason the two cURL scripts may not function together?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have syntax error on your code. Please fix those. For example `$idno=’123’;` should be `$idno='123';`

Now, come to the point about why second curl is not functioning!!! What is the `return` doing after your first curl request??

```
$Response = curl_exec($curl);  
return $Response; <--- its returning you back from here
```

That's why the second curl is always unreachable!! Remove that unwanted `return block`.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I am sure that your suggestions are valid, but I have researched the documentation and found that there is a specific format for multiple cURL requests: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: @Presto that's different issue, and wasn't a part of this question i believe!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a new way to rewrite the code for multi-curl requests.  This is well defined in the cURL documentation here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php